# Website Registration Number is Appearing as a Phone Number Link, Is There a Way to Escape it?

Tags: linker, escaping, inline

```
<html>
  <head>
 </head>
  <body>
   <p>
     <ul>
       <li>Washington registration number: 603-243-896</li>
    </ul>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Our website's Washington Registration number is appearing like a phone number - mistakenly in some cell phones.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening inline for just this occurrence?  I don't want to disable all phone linking in the page ... just for this impostor.

Comment: Show your [mcve]. Note that few people are going to visit that link, which will be dead in an internet moment anyway, making this question less useful for others in the future. If you can make your question stand-alone, you will get more traction.

Answer (score 0):

That is a feature of some web browsers, phone or otherwise. As the field is essentially just plain text the parser just assumes it might be a phone number and will give you the option to try and call it.

It's possible you might be able to trick some of the implementations by obfuscating the string somehow e.g.

```
  <li>Washington registration number: &#x36;&#x30;&#x33;&#x2D;&#x32;&#x34;&#x33;&#x2D;&#x38;&#x39;&#x36;</li>
  <li>Washington registration number: 603-<div></div>243-<div></div>896</li>
  <li>Washington registration number: <img src='invalid_file' alt='603-243-896'></li>
  <li>Washington registration number: <img src='wash_reg_num.png'></li>
```

The last one will definitely work, but is an ugly hack! The penultimate one will probably give page errors.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try the first two and see how it goes.